# Css for YouTube subscribe button

Tags: css, wordpress, youtube

I'd like to make this button 250% bigger. What should I do?

```
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UCEwF2eVRDQNVP-OSmbPt3qQ" data-layout="full" data-count="default"></div>
```

Comment: Probably find the appropriate CSS section and assign bigger numbers for the width and height.

Answer (score 3):

First put the code into a div

```
<div id="ytbutton">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
    <div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UCEwF2eVRDQNVP-OSmbPt3qQ" data-layout="full" data-count="default"></div>
</div>
```

and then style it in your stylesheet.css

```
#ytbutton {

 padding: 1px 50px;
```

}